# Should type aliases be used in local or global scopes?

Tags: c++, c++11

Should one alias c++ types locally or globally? I consider to use "using" or "typedef" to define type alias.  The alias is meant to shorten a long type names involving templates.

Comment: You can't ask that question until you've answered the question of what the alias is meant to accomplish. It's like asking if a variable should be declared in a function or in the global scope; that depends on what the variable is meant to do.

Comment: You should define them in the scope where they make the most sense. Are they globally useful, or only useful in the context of a class or a specific namespace, or just a local convenience inside a function or a specific translation unit, or something else?

Comment: @NicolBolas The alias is meant to shorten a long type names involving templates. I guess that is the only one thing alias can do.